# Make the diagnostic window of monaco editor exceed an allotment panel

Tags: css, panel, monaco-editor

I have made a draggable split panel by https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment.

In the panel panel, I have a monaco editor. when I hover on the monaco editor, a diagnostic window appears. At the moment, the diagnostic window does not exceed the first panel even with `.monaco-hover { z-index: 1000 !important }` in `style.css`. Does anyone know how I could make the diagnostic window exceed the first panel?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-7wvrbj?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";

import "./style.css";

import Editor, { monaco } from "@monaco-editor/react";

monaco
  .init()
  .then((monaco) => {
    monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider("html", {
      provideHover: function (model, position) {
        console.log(position);
        return {
          range: new monaco.Range(
            1,
            1,
            model.getLineCount(),
            model.getLineMaxColumn(model.getLineCount())
          ),
          contents: [
            { value: "**SOURCE**" },
            { value: "hey man, how are you?" }
          ]
        };
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((error) =>
    console.error("An error occurred during initialization of Monaco: ", error)
  );

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toExpand: true
    };
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleChange = (sizes) => {
    if (sizes.length > 1) {
      if (sizes[1] < 31) {
        this.setState({ toExpand: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ toExpand: false });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          minWidth: 200,
          height: "100vh",
          overflowX: "auto",
          width: "auto",
          margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"
        }}
      >
        <Allotment
          vertical
          onChange={this.handleChangeAllotment}
          ref={this.myRef}
        >
          <Allotment.Pane>
            <Editor
              height="30vh"
              language="html"
              value={`
<section>
  <div>
    <span>
      {{ some_value }}
    </span>
  </div>
</section>
    `}
              options={{
                selectOnLineNumber: true,
                lineNumbersMinChars: 0,
                glyphMargin: true,
                readOnly: true,
                hover: {
                  enabled: true
                }
              }}
            />
          </Allotment.Pane>
          <Allotment.Pane preferredSize="0%" minSize={20}>
            short <br /> short <br />
            short <br /> short <br />
            short <br /> short <br />
            short <br /> short <br />
            short <br /> short <br />
            short <br /> short <br />
          </Allotment.Pane>
        </Allotment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant by diagnostic window, but i'm going to assume that it's the box that shows **"hey man, how are you?"** when the code is hovered, i'm also going to assume that you want that box to be shown over the panel where there are **"short"** texts. If that's what you want, then it seems like the cause of why it's not shown on the other panel is because the parent window has `overflow: hidden`, all you need to do is to change the panel `overflow` to `visible`. To do that you can use this CSS:

```
...
div[data-testid="split-view-view"][data-testid="split-view-view"][data-testid="split-view-view"] {
  overflow: visible;
}

div[data-testid="split-view-view"][data-testid="split-view-view"][data-testid="split-view-view"]:nth-child(2) {
  background: white;
}
...
```

Why did I repeat `[data-testid="split-view-view"]` so many times? it's to increase the specificity of the rules (alternatively, you can add `!important` to the `overflow: visible` without repeating the `[data-testid="split-view-view"]`). As for why there is background white for the second panel, it's because when the overflow is not hidden, the elements from the first panel will overlap with the second panel.

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-xqiyhe?file=/src/style.css:47-305) is the working codesandbox fork.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by making it so `.monaco-hover` has `position: fixed`